# How to replace href with value of data-href?

Tags: jquery

I have got html as below

```
<a href="" data-href="/somefile.php?id=10&refcode=/test.php">Hello</a>
```

and I need to replace href with the value  in data-href so that the above becomes something like

```
<a href="/somefile.php?id=10&refcode=/test.php">Hello</a>

//the following doesnt work .. 

$(function() {
 $('a[data-href]').attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

Any suggestions? Basically I want to hide some links for some reason from search engines/bots etc. so I am happy if I can get the above working or if you can suggest any better idea to achieve the same? Thanks.

Comment: Just fyi, I am using latest Jquery.

Comment: @Kay: Specify an actual version number, so that your statement still makes sense in the future.

Comment: This isn't the best idea, a lot of crawlers can now execute javascript.

Comment: @Kay, use `rel=nofollow`. Some bots may ignore this anyway but I'd rather use it than do what you're doing with JS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$(this)` does not refer to the `a` element in this case.

Try

```
$('a[data-href]').each(function() { 
 $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href'));
});
```

using `each(function() {})` will bind the `this` keyword to the `a` element inside the function.

Comment: or just switch `$(this)` to `$('a[data-href]')`.

Comment: @AndyL that won't work. Doing that would only get you the *first* `data-href` value, it won't loop through each element

Comment: good jobs! thanks a lot.. im used Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey to block google seo are link stupid. Cheat: $('div.rc h3.r a[data-href]').each( ... .... .